# Notepad++ one instance per each virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, virtual-desktop

I have problem with opening .txt file on windows-10. Notepad++ is default program to open .txt files, but when there is notepad++ application already  running in other virtual desktop OS will automatically switch me to that other application instance and open file in other desktop. I want to open new instance of notepad++ in my current desktop. Is there a way to accomplish that?

[EDIT]
Multi-Instance is one suggested solution, but this is bad in way that you loose tab functionality. I don't want my taskbar clogged with n++ processes.

One n++ for all desktops - this is killing the purpose of using multiple desktops in first place - keep different work processes and task separated.

Comment: The virtual desktop feature within Windows does not work in this way, a single process is still going to exist, accross all desktops.  In other words it does not work the way you believe it shoudl work.

Comment: you could try to open in multiple instance mode, here a little hint [Notepad++ always in multi instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028209/notepad-always-in-multi-instance) - if somehow defeats the tab functionality - but it could accomplish what you want to achieve...

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that W10 VD works this way, but this way sucks  big time and I wan't to hack it.

Comment: @Zina Yea, I don't wanna loose tab functionality. It works almost OK if I use: Multi-Instance: "Open session in a new instance of Notepad++" and then open new app in each desktop where i plan to use npp. As it is pinned to taskbar it is not bad, but still not perfect solution.

Comment: OK, this last works at random or it changed with some patch. W10 virtual desktops are very unreliable help.

Comment: What about having the same Notepad++ present across all desktops?

Comment: This is better than nothing, but this kind of behavior is opposite of why you use virtual desktops in first place.

Comment: You were offered two solutions so far. Please [edit] the question and extend it by details what exact behavior do you expect and what is the problem with solutions offered in comments. Then maybe I will retract my downvote, but currently I need to put it, because the question is unclear.

Comment: I don't think so, and ive explained why all suggestion are partial solutions. Maybe win10 virtual desktop model is broken, and app devs are not to blame. I wan't one n++ proc per desktops where new files are opened in new tab in the same desktop, flip flop between desktops sucks.

Comment: Keep the process per desktop and drag instead of double click to open the file?

Comment: Are you fine with some preparation work upon opening new desktop?  (Please use @miroxlav in your comments so I can see when you answer. Thanks.)

Comment: @miroxlav Yes, especially if it can be scripted like some batch.

Comment: @Seth I am doing something like this most of the time. And it is tiresome. Drag, or File -> Open.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **hack** that may work for you.

> Requirements:

1. **Two Portable Notepad++ in two separate folders.** (It may work with one NPP installation, but two separate Notepad++ seem to be cleaner approach. You may also not need Portable Notepad++, but it may be easier that way.)
2. Two or more virtual desktops

> **How does it work:** (I have **animated GIF** at the end to demonstrate this steps).

1. Open **Notepad++** folder on the first Virtual Desktop.
2. Right click on **Notepad++.exe** to create a shortcut.
3. Right click on the newly created shortcut and go to its **properties**.
4. Add `-multiInst` in the target section. (The text is case-sensitive, and there is a space at the beginning.)
5. Click OK to close the properties.
6. Double click on the shortcut.
7. It should open the new instance of Notepad++ in that virtual desktop.
8. Now switch to another Virtual Desktop. Open its own Notepad++ folder. And follow steps 2-7.
9. To keep things organized, I kept two folders, `VM1` and `VM2` with the notepad++ folders in them. (VM being **V**irtual **M**achine)

> **Some Final Notes:**

- This would work as long as the Notepad++ window in a virtual machine was `Active`, i.e. you had **touched** it at least once.
- This is because when you open text file (or your source code files), it opens in the `Last Active` instance of Notepad++.
- I am assuming that you are not changing your virtual desktops very frequently, since that would nullify the actual purpose of virtual desktops.

> **Here is the animated GIF.**

- You can right click on GIF and open it in new tab to see the steps clearly.
- GIF shows steps on one virtual desktop, you need to replicate it on the other too.

  [image]

I hope it is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Super detailed answer, will try and see how it works. "Last Active instance" part is a little downer, but i hope I can adapt.

Comment: Yup. It is a kind of little downer. BTW your question and the approach is pretty interesting. I have not used Virtual Desktop as much as I should. I may try this.

Comment: +1 Great, thanks! Now I can use npp without the "auto desktop switch" that was driving me crazy