# New notepad++ window for each Windows 10 virtual desktop?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, virtual-desktop

I use the Windows 10 virtual desktop feature to declutter my workspace - each virtual desktop being used for a different set of tasks.

The problem I'm having is that I tend to want to use notepad++ on each of the my virtual desktops - but notepad++ seems to only allow one instance. When I open a text file in a different virtual desktop, it will switch back to the virtual desktop that initially had notepad++ open.

You can create multiple windows of notepad++ by dragging tabs outside the window, but notepad++ will still open new files in the original instance.

Is there any tricks for easily working with notepad++ and windows 10 virtual desktops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ one instance per each virtual desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/1074797/notepad-one-instance-per-each-virtual-desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce and solve your problem by changing the Multi-instance settings. Just go to

- Settings

  - Multi-Instance

and select: **Always in multi-instance mode**.

After restarting Notepad++ you should be able to use different instances on your desktops.

Comment: This opens a new instance of Notepad++ even if there is an instance open in the current virtual desktop.